# blender render is broken

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

my render output looks broken. the main mesh is completely missing and the water part looks broken. I added the bushes as particles. does anyone know how to fix this?[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, zen .. glad you've got a fix! This looks like a simple slip-up in the end, and is not a very searchable item for the archive, so I think it's OK to close By all means edit and flag to reopen if you object.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's the result of a simple mistake.

Comment: im sorry i resolved it in a few hours but forgot to close it after the 24 hour cooldown

Comment: No problem .. the self-answer is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't applied the geometry nodes. Applying it and removing all hidden objects fixed the problem.